# Target Dynamic ID and hide the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic html elements that renders in a for loop the dynamic parent element has a dynamic id, how can I hide the dynamic elements or the container and its content if the id which is dynamic has a value lets say "Product".

Thank you in advance.

This is the dynamic elements that i rendered using for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < a_data.products.length; i++) {
    produst_list += '<a href="#" class="plLinkToFull" data-sn="' + a_data.products[i].serial + '" id="' + a_data.products[i].productName + '">';
    produst_list += '<div class="plProductContainer">';
    produst_list += '   <div class="plProductBTN">';
    //produst_list += '       <div class="plProductThumb pull-left ' + (a_data.products[i].pid === 'TE80'?'apMaximumPanelTi8':'apMaximumPanel') + '"></div>';
    produst_list += '       <div class="plProductThumb pull-left ' + getPanelClsss(a_data.products[i].pid) + '"></div>';
    produst_list += '       <div class="plProductLeft">';
    produst_list += '         <h6 style="margin-bottom: -5px;">' + a_data.products[i].productName + '</h6>';
    produst_list += '   <div class="plLowerStatusSN"><span>' + a_data.products[i].serial + '</span></div>';
    produst_list += '        </div><div class="plLowerStatus">';
    produst_list += '         <div class="' + ((a_data.products[i].remainingDays > 0) ? "plIconGreen" : "plIconRed") + '">';
    produst_list += '           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" style="">&nbsp; </span></div>';
    produst_list += '          <span class="' + ((a_data.products[i].remainingDays > 0) ? "plExpiryOK" : "plExpiredDate") + '">Expire: <strong>' + a_data.products[i].expirationDate + '</strong></span>';
    produst_list += '       </div></div></div></a>';
}
```

Comment: Value of which element ? Question is not clear..

Comment: the <a> element which is the parent container of all the content. Thank you.

Comment: `<a>` element contains so many child elements.. Which element you want to target ?

Comment: does this mean you want to hide everything inside the `<a>`? If so just add another class to the first div and hide the element using css.

Comment: the <a> element itself which has the dynamic id.

Comment: yes @JanR. Thank you

Comment: This is bad practice for coding HTML where you put a lot of elements which are not expected to be inside the a tag. The answer by Mohammad below looks good though.

Answer (score 1):

With filter :

```
$('a.plLinkToFull').filter(function(){
   return this.id.contains("product");
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this:

```
$('.plLinkToFull').prev('id') = i;
```

or

```
$('.plLinkToFull').attr("id", i);
```

The i have to send to new Method, for saving the loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var id = 'Product';
$('a[id*="'+id+'"]').hide();
```

if you want to hide it by clicking use event delegation

```
var el = 'a[id*="'+id+'"]';
$('body').on('click',el,function(){
$(this).hide();
});
```